# Sort and uniq format to thousand separator

Tags: shell-script, numeric-data

How to format line counts after sort and uniq add thousand separator

Sample Input:

```
1000 A
3000 B
```

Output:

```
1,000 A
3,000 B
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numfmt` from GNU Coreutils:

```
printf '1000 A\n3000 B\n' | numfmt --field=1 --grouping
1,000 A
3,000 B
```

The result that you get may depend on your locale.